# Checkbox is checked when go to Edit page - PHP HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a situation where I have create a new information after submit a new info, the information is a success into the database.

But when I click on the 'Edit' page, all other information is displayed. But for the input type checkbox, the information does not display at all.

```
<tr>
   <td>Transaction</td>
   <td>
      <div class="checkbox check-default check-success">
         <input id="f1" type="checkbox" value="1" name="Tbox" <?= ( $modules['transaction']=='1'?  "checked" : "") ?>>
         <label for="f1"></label>
      </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I wonder what I am missing. Please help, thanks.

Comment: What information? The checkbox? More code needed.

Comment: yes, the information inside the checkbox does not appear. I mean the checkbox does not check for the checked box but as well for the unchecked box.

Comment: What is `$modules['transaction']`. Are you using XHTML? Then you need ` />` at the end of your self-closing HTML tags.

Comment: for $modules['transaction'].

The code is taking the info from this variable: 

$ssc = ; //this is sql statement

$rssc = $db->sql_query($ssc) or $db->sql_error($ssc);
$rwsc_check = $db->sql_fetchrow($rssc);
$modules = unserialize($rwsc_check['MODULES']);

Comment: and no im not using xhtml

Comment: Have you echoed out `$modules['transaction']` to verify that its value is `1`?

Comment: I did, and what I get is a blank page when I go to the page again. So im guessing it does have something with my query right?

Comment: many reason for this because this code is correct if $modules['transaction'] var is 1, so plz check other source like jquery  etc

Comment: alright, thank you for sharing your concern. I will check

Comment: Change `( $modules['transaction']=='1'?  "checked" : "")` to `( $modules['transaction']=='1'?  "checked='checked'" : "")`, and try.

Comment: Still does't work. There is no changes

Answer (score 0):

Remove the value=1 in your code.

Use this code below

```
    <input id="f1" type="checkbox"  name="Tbox" <?= ( $modules['transaction']=='1'?  "checked" : "") ?>>
```

Comment: Value only defines what is sent on success, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_value.asp .

Comment: Yah, but in this case values=1 can be used as True, so when returning checkbox is checked.

Comment: As far as I checked ( see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/bb5r6sbu/ ), value does not determine the checked status.

Answer (score 0):

You specified the value of a default input `value = 1`, removes `value = 1`
try

```
<input id="f1" type="checkbox"  name="Tbox" <?= ( $modules['transaction']=='1'?  "checked" : "") ?>>
```

Comment: How is this answer different than the one 7 minutes earlier?

Comment: I even do things as this base on the comments from the users
<input id="f1" type="checkbox"  value="1" name="Tbox" <?= ( $modules['transaction']=='1'? "checked='checked'" : "") ?>>